# json decode exception python

Tags: python, json

---

### Sample server

I have a python script as mentioned below copied to /var/www/cgi-bin folder with permissions set to 775.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

 print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "testing...\n";

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi

from jsonrpc import handleCGI, ServiceMethod
import json
from datetime import datetime

@ServiceMethod
def echo():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handleCGI()
```

---

### Sample Client

Now, Iam accessing this simple echo service using the below client code.

```
from jsonrpc import ServiceProxy
import json

s = ServiceProxy(`"http://localhost/cgi-bin/t2.py"`)
print s.echo()
```

1/ Iam getting the below error when i run the above client. Any thoughts? 
2/  Is there any issue with httpd.conf settings?

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonrpc/proxy.py", line 43, in __call__
    resp = loads(respdata)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonrpc/json.py", line 211, in loads
    raise JSONDecodeException('Expected []{}," or Number, Null, False or True')
jsonrpc.json.JSONDecodeException: Expected []{}," or Number, Null, False or True
```

Note: Iam using the example mentioned at the below link using cgi way of handling json.

http://json-rpc.org/wiki/python-json-rpc

Please let me know.

Thanks!
Santhosh

Comment: Please post the JSON string your script is trying to decode.

Comment: Iam just trying to call echo first. Cant we call echo ServiceMethod? echo method is defined under t2.py

Comment: Anybody please. I got stucked here!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but I found this question when I had the same problem. In hopes it helps someone else, I will post my solution.

In my case it was as simple (stupid) as making the python file itself executable. i.e. chmod 755 t2.py